# automatic sub-domain registration

Tags: dns

I'm new at DNS world, did some readings in the Internet and wanted to know if I came to the right conclusions. I want to build a system where users are able to create new sub-domains of existing registered domains automatically:

My system provides services to different companies, these services are hosted in my system or some cloud provider. Lets call my system "services" and some company "company1". I want to offer "company1" my services and have its users access these services through "company1" new sub-domain, when "company1" has an already registered domain company1.com. I want "company1" admin user be able to control and choose the sub-domain via my system when he registers his company in my system, and have the whole thing automatic. If i understand correctly:

1. if the admin would want to use a sub-domain like services.company1.com this will be a problem since I would need to update the authoritative name-servers of company1.com which I don't know who they are, and even if I have a way to know them (and from reading a bit I see that I do have a way), I don't know if every such name server will allow such updates from some external source, connectivity issues etc
2. if the admin would like to use a sub-domain like company1.services.com then I can achieve this by having my own dns server which I will register the services.com domain for and actually manage all these company sub-domains in my own dns server. This means though that all companies will have to have a sub-domain under my domain services.com

Please correct me if I have a wrong view on how DNS works.

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### services.company1.com

To provide this kind of domain name to your customer, you will need their collaboration. A lot of companies provides this kind of feature by asking you to point an alias ([CNAME Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record)) to a specific server.

#### Examples of concrete usage

```
blog.company1.com.      3600    IN  CNAME   domains.tumblr.com.
shop.company1.com.      3600    IN  CNAME   myapp.herokuapp.com.
git.company1.com.       3600    IN  CNAME   bitbucket.org.
```

Here's some links to the documentation of companies offering this feature:

- [BitBucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Associate+an+Existing+Domain+with+Your+Account)
- [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)
- [Tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains)

#### Sample client zone file

So in your case your customer DNS zone will contain something like that:

```
services.company1.com.      3600    IN  CNAME   domains.services.com.
```

where `domains.services.com.` will be the server that handles the subdomain authentication

### company1.services.com

To provide to your customers *company1.services.com*, you don't have to manage your own DNS server, you just have to be able to add a [wildcard record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) to point all the subdomains to your application. It will be the role of your application to filter your service per subdomains.

#### Sample service zone file

For example (where 0.0.0.0 is your service IP address):

```
*.services.com.     3600    IN  A   0.0.0.0
```