# How to create a site instance per subdomain

Tags: web, subdomain, url-routing, uservoice

I would like to create a web platform where each customer get its own site like [uservoice.com](https://www.uservoice.com/)

**Example:**

- Main website : uservoice.com
- Customer 1: *cust1-subdomain*.uservoice.com
- Customer 2 : *cust2-subdomain*.uservoice.com

The objective is that the customer can enter its site via its own url & login page.

Does anyone know how to do that? How to avoid a sub-directory by subdomain and copy all the files? I am looking for a clean and scalable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution is a name-based virtual host.

For example the domain cust2-subdomain.uservoice.com will display the content located in a different folder than your DocumentRoot but the address will be unchanged. The server will recognize the domain and send the appropriate content.

---

If you are using apache: You will need to uncomment this line in the httpd.conf file if not already uncommented:

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Then you should edit /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin you@uservoice.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/docs/uservoice.com"
    ServerName uservoice.com
    ServerAlias www.uservoice.com
    ErrorLog "logs/uservoice.com/error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/uservoice.com/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin cust2@uservoice.com
    DocumentRoot "/users/customers/cust2/WWW"
    ServerName cust2-subdomain.uservoice.com
    ServerAlias www.cust2-subdomain.uservoice.com
    ErrorLog "logs/cust2/error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/cust2/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

The first section is for your site and the second one for cust2's site. So cust2 will put his site into the WWW folder located in his home directory. You will put your content in your old DocumentRoot. (You will need to customize /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf).

Comment: In order to access cust2-subdomain.uservoice.com do I still need to create a DNS subdomain or it will be handled by Apache and I just need to have uservoice.com registred in my dns?

Comment: Yes. 
Also you can use Wildcard DNS record.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441418/automatic-sub-domain-registration

Comment: You can register all sub-domains with this:
*.uservoice.com

Comment: Yes I will use a wildcard dns record.

Comment: As I am developing an asp.net platform  I will use MVC routing. I could also use iis rewrite module to achieve my goal.